# rosdep initialization error

Tags: ros, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$ sudo rosdep init

ERROR: cannot download default sources list from:
https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list

Website may be down.

none of the answer like
$ sudo -E rosdep init

i am using ubuntu 14.04 and working behind a proxy.

rosdep version version 0.11.2-1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212358/rosdep-initialization-error/) by [Sabyasachi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22964/sabyasachi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-06-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-06-28**:
What's the version of rosdep? You could edit your statement to add the result of `$ dpkg -p python-rosdep|grep Ver`.

**Comment by [Sabyasachi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22964/sabyasachi/) on 2015-06-29**:
version
0.11.2-1
and how to edit the statement
what to to do next

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-06-29**:
To edit your question click the "edit" link at the bottom of the text field, next to the Comments heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're behind a proxy you will need to configure rosdep to use the proxy.

There are a bunch of threads on that already:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/54150/rosdep-initialization-error/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/193610/error-in-rosdep-initialization/
- https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/271

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1